# Equivalent of Haskell's $ operator in OCaml

Tags: haskell, ocaml, operator-precedence

Is there an equivalent to Haskell's `$` operator in OCaml, or do I have to rely on brackets? See for example,

```hs
multiplyByFive 5 + 1 = 26
```

but

```hs
multiplyByFive $ 5 + 1 = 30
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The standard library defines both a right-to-left application operator `@@`

```
let compose h g f x = h @@ g @@ f x
```

and left-to-right application operator `|>`:

```ml
let rev_compose f g h x = x |> f |> g |> h
```

with the expected associativity (right for `@@` and left for `|>`).

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for `@@`

```ml
# let multiplyby5 a = 5 * a;;
val multiplyby5 : int -> int = <fun>
# multiplyby5 5 + 1;;
- : int = 26
# multiplyby5 @@ 5 + 1;;
- : int = 30
```

Answer (score 7):

In OCaml, you can use the application operator (added in OCaml 4.01) to achieve the same.

```
multiplyByFive @@ 5 + 1
- : int = 30
```

The application operator carries right precedence so the right side of the operator is evaluated first, similar to Haskell's application operator ($). You might also want to look into the pipeline operator (|>) in OCaml which is a reverse application operator similar to the (&) operator in Haskell.